# How To Raise a "File Download" in ASP and prevent hotlink

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, download

I have this code in PHP:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path.$filename));
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($filename));
readfile($path.$filename);
```

In first time, i use this in asp:

```
<%
    Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment; filename=download.xls"
%>
```

I prevent **"hotlink"** too

Comment: Once the file is on their machine, they don't need the URL to pass it to another user, they can just copy the file.

Comment: some like this: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/601802-chopping-file-while-sending-via-asp-response-binary-write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set ObjStr = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
ObjStr.Type = 1 'AdBinary – Binário
ObjStr.Open

ObjStr.LoadFromFile "D:\Folder\edital.pdf"

varBuffer = ObjStr.Read

Response.buffer = true

Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment;"
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.CacheControl = "public"

Response.BinaryWrite varBuffer
```