# Is it possible to embed the username/password into and ASP file to access files when anonymous access is disabled?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I'm redesigned a login system where I work and currently if someone know the path to a file they may be able to access it even if they are not logged in at all. So far I've researched and come up with 2 ways to prevent this.

1. Disable anonymous access and have the file brought in by the webpage. This is what I would prefer to do for now since it wouldn't require moving the files around and it seems to be relatively easy to implement. The problem with this is that if I disable anonymous access the file trying to access the document they requires the username/password. Is it possible to have to username/password as part of the ASP file to eliminate this?
2. The other option is to move the files outside of the website and elsewhere on the server and have the webpage bring in the file similar the first option. I want to eventually get to this method, currently it would take much more time to do this though since we would have to move the files for all of our users as well as change the programs that generate the different reports to output to their new locations.

Comment: Is this an Intranet based application? Are using active directory?

Comment: The system is currently only accessible internally but is being designed to be available through the internet. The login system is not using active directory, it's database driven.

Comment: Why not just turn off anonymous access and have the users log in that need access to the files?

Comment: That's the way the current system is. The problem with that though is that the users can still access the files if they know direct url. By the same principle they could access other users' files as well. It's unlikely it would ever happen, especially with some of the file/directory names that we use but we want that possibility removed completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a basis for the code elsewhere on this site but it didn't quite work the way I needed it to.

[How To Raise a "File Download" in ASP and prevent hotlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004190/how-to-raise-a-file-download-in-asp-and-prevent-hotlink/5004900#5004900)

```
Dim curUser, curDir, curtype
curUser = Request.QueryString("user")
curDir = Request.QueryString("dir")
curType = Request.QueryString("type")

If curUser = Session("homefolder") Then
Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
adoStream.Type = 1
adoStream.Open()

adoStream.LoadFromFile "C:/path/to/" & curUser & curDir

Response.Buffer = true
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
Response.Clear
If curType = ".TXT" Then
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
Else
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
End If

Response.flush
Do While Not adoStream.eos
    Response.BinaryWrite adoStream.Read(1024 * 8)
    Response.flush
Loop
Response.End()
adoStream.close
Set adoStream=nothing
Else
Response.Redirect "denied.asp"
End If
```

The file is brought in and displayed within the browser. If the user tries to see another user's files they are simply redirected. I'm currently only dealing with PDF and TXT file but it will be easy to add new files types if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a rewrite rule in IIS.
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

You can also do this with a Request Filtering rule in IIS.
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules/filteringrule/appliesto

Answer (score 0):

"*Is it possible to have to username/password as part of the ASP file to eliminate this?*"

Yes, if you only want to restrict access to .asp files  Session variables tend to be overused in Classic ASP but this is one situation where it is completely appropriate to use one.  At the start of all your restricted pages you could have something like

```
<% If Session("loggedin") <> 1 then Response.Redirect("login.asp") End If %>
```

Then you need to find a classic asp login script which sets a session variable.  Google or Bing should come up with plenty, but here are a couple of links for you

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121723/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/050499-1.shtml

https://web.archive.org/web/20210323190338/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/021600-1.shtml

Edit - http server request code. I haven't tested this

```
Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xml.open "GET","http://fullurlto/yourpdffile.pdf", false, "yourusername", "yourpassword"
xml.send 
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.write xml.responseText
```

Comment: The system is already setup this way. What I'm trying to prevent is direct access to the files for each user (primarily pdf). What I was was really trying for is to be able to have the windows logon username/password embedded in the page that retrieves the data, for that to do any good though I still need a way to restrict direct access to the pdf files.

Comment: You might be able to use a server http request.  I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: I ended up not being able to get this one to work quite right, I believe due to our server setup, but I was able to find a solution and get it to fit my needs. The new script doesn't require the username/password but is still able to display the files as needed. I'm posting the script I ended up using.